# How do I change the name of the executable that I'm installing using CPack?

Tags: c++, cmake, cpack

I do apologize in advanced if this sounds like something trivial. I am new to using CMake and CPack.

I am currently trying to build my own compiler as a side project, and I want to test out how CPack will install my project.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file that I have at the root of my project folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Simple-C-Compiler VERSION 0.01)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(COMPILER_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

add_library(include INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(include INTERFACE include/)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(phases)
add_subdirectory(compiler)
add_subdirectory(tests)

target_link_libraries(compiler lexer)
target_link_libraries(tester lexer)

add_compile_options(-Wall)

install(TARGETS compiler DESTINATION bin)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_EXECUTABLES "compiler" "Simple-C")
include(CPack)
```

When I try to install my compiler, by doing:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make install
```

I get the following output:

```
[ 22%] Built target lib
[ 55%] Built target lexer
[ 77%] Built target compiler
[100%] Built target tester
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/compiler
```

CPack installed my compiler as "compiler" not "Simple-C". I want the name of the executable being installed to be "Simple-C". How do I go about doing that in my CMakeLists.txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the name of a target with the following command:

```
set_target_properties(compiler PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME Simple-C)
```

This must be called after the `add_subdirectory(compiler)`

As a side note, the commands you mentionned did not invoke cpack. In order to invoke cpack, you would need to run the [cpack command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cpack.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RENAME` option of CMake `install`. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html

In short

```
install(TARGETS compiler DESTINATION bin RENAME Simple-C)
```

Comment: I just tried this, and I'm still getting the same problem.